# как заанимировать выражение лица персонажа

Tags: unity3d, анимация, разработка-игр

подскажите пожалуйста,хочу сделать 2D шутер на Unity, где у игрока при стрельбе меняется выражение лица, для этого я сделал два идентичных персонажа (в вектарной графике), но с разными эмоциями (обычная и злая), но не знаю как заанимировать их смену при стрельбе

Comment: Почитайте про шейпы.